# Client-Library sfound but could not be loaded. Check compile-target and library compatibility! - happens when want to connect to the database Lazarus

Tags: phpmyadmin, pascal, lazarus, zeos

i just installed zeos on lazarus on linux mint device, and created database in phpmyadmin.
when I enable Zquery to true, an error like this occurs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VCDF.png)

does anyone know why this is happening,
did I write the LibraryLocation address wrong on ZConnection?

Comment: Or a version mismatch between dll and intended uses. E.g. mysql is hopelessly versioned.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Make sure your mysql library matches versionwise and 32/64-bit wise